# Yii2 gridview showing more records than the table

Tags: yii2

I have two mysql tables:

**People** with 51 records

> - id
> - name
> - ...

**People Stats** with 131 records

> - id
> - peopleID
> - date
> - stars
> - ...

if i set this at models/peopleSearch.php

```
$query->joinWith('peopleStats');
```

GridView shows 131 records. How could I set that join to just get records for the last day (a query with MAX(date) ) on every people item for GridView to show just the 51 records with the latest data?

Thanks

Comment: use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.....

Comment: Try this one like.............     `$query = People::find();`
`$query->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'people_state', "people_table_id = people_state_table_id");`

Comment: Thank you Vishu, but that one seems to make just the left outer join which is the same that $query->joinWith('peopleStats'); does. What I need is to join date just with those records with the most recent date in peoplestats table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem for `ActiveDataProvider`-backed `GridView`. The grid needs to know how many total models you have in your dataset. At the same time, fetching and instantiating all models just to count them would be extremely inefficient. That's why `ActiveDataProvider` gets total model count from SQL, assuming that every row in result set corresponds to a model.

Now, you've introduced a `JOIN` to your query. This increases the amount of rows in result set (from 51 to 131 in your case). Total model count is not the only thing that breaks, you should also have a problem with pagination. Note that the `all()` function that you might use to get all models (as in `People::find()->joinWith('peopleStats')->all()` is smart enough to remove redundant rows, so you'd get exactly 51 models with `all()`.

Now, there are several workarounds. First of all, the only reason to do a `joinWith()` in a data provider is when you need to filter or sort on related data. If this is not the case, use `with()`, and you'll be fine.

If you do need to filter/sort on related data, there is another workaround, select only columns from your main table `->select('people.*')`. You can still reference related data in your grid view, it will just be lazy-loaded.

If your result set is small, and especially if you're not planning to use pagination, consider switching to `ArrayDataProvider`.

In your specific case, I suggest you just make another `hasOne` relation like `peopleStatsLast`, and in it implement the query that selects only the last set of stats for a given person, then lazy-load it. Check [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) for more information.

Comment: Thats exactly my case. I need to filter+sort those fields. Ill try to set the new relation with hasOne

Comment: You might want to use `ArrayDataProvider` instead of complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

should be this query

```
$query = People::find()->
   join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'people_state', "people_table_id = people_state_table_id")->
   where("(peopleID, date) in ( select peopleID, max(date) from  peopleStats 
   group by peopleID)");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @scaisEdge. Im getting this error:unespected ",". This is the query:

<pre>
$query = People::find()
 ->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'PeopleStats', "People.socialID = PeopleStats.socialID")
 ->where(
  (
      People.socialID, PeopleStats.date
  ) in ( 
      select PeopleStats.socialID, max(date) from PeopleStats 
      group by People.socialID
  )
 );
</pre>

Comment: I'm sorry i have forgot the quotes ".  i have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query like.....

```
$query = People::find(); 
$query->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'people_state', "people_table_id = people_state_table_id");
```